Angular velocity of stationary observer
I am studying Kerr metric in Boyer Lindquist coordinates and having trouble in understanding the components of angular velocity of stationary observer with constant r and $\theta$ motion w.r.t external universe which is defined as $u^\alpha=\left((-g_{tt})^{-1/2},0,0,0 \right)$. Here $u^\phi=0$. There is another observer ZAMO who has r and $\theta$ constant but $u_{\phi}=0$
$$u_{\alpha}=\left(-(-g^{tt})^{-1/2},0,0,0 \right)$$
whose 4-velocity is
$u^\alpha=\left((-g^{tt})^{1/2},\frac{-g^{t \phi}}{(-g^{tt})^{-1/2}},0,0) \right)$
My confusion is these $u_{\alpha}$ and $u^{\alpha}$ components. I Know that one is vector and other is dual vector but why $u_{\phi}=0$ for ZAMO and $u^{\phi}$ is not?

ZAMO stands for Zero Angular Momentum Observer. The angular momentum of a worldline in Boyer-Lindquist coordinates is exactly $u_\phi$. So for a ZAMO $u_\phi=0$ per definition. Since
$$ u^\phi = u_t g^{t\phi} + u_\phi g^{\phi\phi}$$
$u^\phi$ is non-zero for a ZAMO.

so why $u^{\phi}$ is not zero ?

Because $u_t$ and $g^{t\phi}$ are not.

can't we write $u_{\phi}=u^{t}g_{t \phi}+u^{\phi}g_{\phi \phi}$ ? is $g_{t \phi}$ and $g_{\phi \phi}$ zero ?

Yes, you can write it like that. No, neither $g_{t\phi}$ nor $g_{\phi\phi}$ is zero.

so what makes $u_{\phi}$ zero here ?
